# Facebook reporting "og:type=website" but scraped reports "og:type=article"!

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a news.read application already accepted by Facebook, but with some Wordpress update it stopped working, because Facebook assumes that "og:type" of my articles are set to "website" and therefore nothing works.

The problem is that the source I can check through my browser has a proper "og:type" and even when clicking "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" it reports the proper og:type!

Is this some kind of bug or am I missing something?

Here's an example URL: http://www.jornalinsolito.com/um-ato-sexual-que-dura-ha-47-milhoes-de-anos/

Any help is useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

[checkout here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.jornalinsolito.com/um-ato-sexual-que-dura-ha-47-milhoes-de-anos/)